# How to query dom element ID with JQuery Template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I would like to manipulate values on a JQuery template, perhaps with an inline expression or function.  I am having trouble selecting the elements in order which to grab their values to perform these tasks.  Here's the code:

```
<td class="currency">
            <span id="discounted_amount">${Globalize.format(DiscountAmount, "c2")}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="currency">
            <span id="totalAmt">${Globalize.format(InvoiceAmount, "c2")}</span>
        </td>
```

I'm trying to basically evaluate the discounted_amount, and if there's a value, to subtract that from the totalAmt.  I would like to do this on the client, without any further ajax calls. I've seen some examples of this where people have used {{if}} {{else}} {{/if}} or {{html somefunction();}}.  I've just not had any success myself.  Here's the function I'd like to call, or a similar structure based on whatever works best for the jquery template implementation.

```
function calculateDiscountedTotal() {
        var discountedAmount = $('#discounted_amount').val();
        var totalAmt = $('#total_amount').val();
        var discountedTotal = function () {
            return totalAmt - discountedAmount;
        }
        return discountedTotal();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what template system you're using but it looks like you want the element text not the value. Value is reserved for input elements.

```
var discountedAmount = parseInt($('#discountered_amount').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateDiscountedTotal() {
        var discountedAmount = parseInt( $('#discounted_amount').text());
        var totalAmt = parseInt($('#totalAmt').text());
        var discountedTotal = function () {
            return totalAmt - discountedAmount;
        }
        return discountedTotal();
    }
    console.log(calculateDiscountedTotal());
});`enter code here`
```

Comment: I tried this, but because it's using Jquery template engine, both discountedAmount and totalAmt return as NaN. Thanks for the reply though.